# Populating cell array using lookup table

Tags: matlab, lookup-tables

I have a 2D `matrix` containing only integers. I also have a cell array `tickerList`that contains names of equity tickers. The number of columns in `matrix`equals the number of elements in `tickerList`.

I am trying to create `cellArrayNew` by replacing the integers within `matrix` by its corresponding names in `tickerList`. So, for example, if `matrix(1,1)=3`and `tickerList(3)='S&P 500'`, I would like to have `cellArrayNew(1,1)='S&P 500'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the matrix as an index into `tickerList`:

```
% Sample column names
tickerList = {'Col1' 'Col2' 'Col3'};

% Example matrix   
N = numel(tickerList);
matrix = randi(N, [4, N]);

% The matrix is already in index form, so just index:
cellArrayNew = tickerList(matrix);
```

If the matrix contains indices that are somehow *not* in `tickerList`, use [`ismember`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

```
% Make some elements 'NaN';
matrix(rand(size(matrix)) < 0.2) = NaN;

% Determine which elements are in tickerList, 
% as well as where they are precisely
[isin, I] = ismember(matrix, 1:N);

% Construct new matrix
cellArrayNew = repmat({NaN}, size(matrix)); % <- use any filler you want
cellArrayNew(isin) = tickerList(I(isin))
```

Result of my example:

```
cellArrayNew = 
    'Col2'    'Col1'    [ NaN]
    'Col3'    [ NaN]    'Col2'
    'Col3'    'Col3'    'Col3'
    'Col3'    'Col1'    'Col2'
```

Comment: Why do you use `ismember`. From your solution I just learned that `I` is equal to `matrix`. So, the very simple solution seems to be

`cellArrayNew = tickerList(matrix)`

Am I missing something?

Comment: @Andi ...very true. Must have been sleeping there :)

Comment: @Andi just keep it in mind for the future then -- `ismember` allows you to do the same for matrices which *may* have elements that exceed the length of `tickerList` (the situation I usually encounter, which is probably why my muscle memory kicked in while typing this answer☺)

Comment: ...Your solution is fine with regards to my original problem! I am now looking for a solution given `matrix` may also contain `NaN`.

Comment: @Andi ...and there you have it, the most common use case :D (see my latest edits)